# How can I send raw hex data via the ruby UDPSocket class?

Tags: ruby, sockets, udp

I am trying to send some hexadecimal data via the UDPSocket class to a server.

```
require 'socket'
socket = UDPSocket.new
socket.send('230055', 0, '192.168.1.205', 50000)
```

where 230055 is the hex command I am trying to send. This actually works if I take the hex, convert it to ascii and send that. Is it possible to just send the raw hex data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to send three bytes: 0x23, 0x00, and 0x55 into the socket. That can be done using `Array.pack`:

```
socket.send([0x23, 0x00, 0x55].pack('C*'), 0, '192.168.1.205', 50000)
```

That will convert the three hexadecimal numbers into three unsigned bytes, that’s what the 'C*' format string specifies, and send them through the socket. Look at the documentation of [`Array.pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-pack) if you need some other conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'socket'
require 'parseconfig'
wifi_bridge_ip = '192.168.1.205'
wifi_bridge_port = 50000

#define lamp states
lamp_on = "\x22\x00\x55"
lamp_off = "\x21\x00\x55"

case ARGV[0]
when "on"
  socket = UDPSocket.new
  socket.send(lamp_on, 0, wifi_bridge_ip, wifi_bridge_port)

when "off"
  socket = UDPSocket.new
  socket.send(lamp_off, 0, wifi_bridge_ip, wifi_bridge_port)
```

.....

```
when "color"
  #set color argument to be an integer
  passed_color = ARGV[1].to_i
  #puts "passed_color is #{passed_color}"

  #convert that to a hex value
  colorcode = passed_color.to_s(16)
  #puts "hex color code is #{colorcode}"

  #send the value being sure to encode the color code into hex
  set_color = "\x20#{colorcode.hex.chr}\x55"
  socket = UDPSocket.new
  socket.send(set_color, 0, wifi_bridge_ip, wifi_bridge_port)
```

Full code is available on [github](https://github.com/brandon-dacrib/cloverleaf/blob/master/app/modules/limitlessled-rgb.rb).

I basically converted the values inputted values hex and sent that. Works.